Question on ODE involving mollifiers from Taylor's book on PDEs
In Taylor's third book on PDEs chapter 16, the author discusses quasilinear symmetric hyperbolic systems of the form
$$\partial_{t}u=A^{k}(t,x,u)\partial_{k}u+g(t,x,u)$$
with some initial condition $u(0,\cdot)=f(\cdot)\in H^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, for smooth symmetric matrix-valued functions $A^{k}$ and a smooth function $g$. Now, the strategy of showing existence and uniquenuess of solutions to this equation is to investigate the "mollified equation"
$$\partial_{t}u_{\varepsilon}=J_{\varepsilon}A^{k}(t,x,J_{\varepsilon}u_{\varepsilon})\partial_{k}J_{\varepsilon}u_{\varepsilon}+J_{\varepsilon}g(t,x,J_{\varepsilon}u_{\varepsilon})$$
where $J_{\varepsilon}u=\varphi_{\varepsilon}\ast u$ for $\varphi_{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ denotes a Friedrich mollifier. Now, he is claiming that this is a simply ODE and hence admits local solutions $u_{\varepsilon}$. (In the end, the idea is to show that these solutions converge to a solution to the nonlinear problem as $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$).
Now, I am stuck in understanding how to solve this mollified equation: I do understand that the mollified equations just involves the time-derivative on $u_{\varepsilon}$, since $\partial_{k}J_{\varepsilon}u_{\varepsilon}=(\partial_{k}\varphi_{\varepsilon})\ast u_{\varepsilon}$. However, isn't it an integro-differential equation rather than an ODE? I mean, it contains an involution. In particular, it is non-local.
Furthermore, as a follow-up question, the book seems to state a bit below (in the proof of Theorem 1.2) that the solution $u_{\varepsilon}$ is in the space $C(I,H^{k})\cap C^{1}(I,H^{k-1})$. Can someone elaborate on this?
EDIT: Of course, in the special case of linear hyperbolic systems, i.e. $A^{k}(t,x,\cdot)=const$ for all $(t,x)$ and $g(t,x,\cdot)$ linear for all $(t,x)$, things become more easy: In this case, the mollified equation is an ODE in Sobolev spaces of the form $\partial_{t}u=T(t)u+f(t)$ for some bounded operator $T$ and can be solved using standard techniques of solving PDEs in Banach spaces via semigroups. However, in the general, non-liner, case things become much more involved and it is not obvious to me.

I guess he thinks of the equation as a Banach valued ODE $u'=Au$, with $A$ a bounded operator. Cauchy's local existence theorem can be reframed in this setting

@PieroD'Ancona I see, thanks for your comment. But it would be a quite complicated (non-linear, non-homogenous) ODE in Banach spaces in which the opreator depends in addition on time, i.e. $u^{\prime}=A(t,u)u+g(t,u)$. Do you have any literature on that?

If you want to solve $u(t)=u_0+\int_0^t F(s,u(s))ds$ you just need that the right hand side is a contraction on some closed ball of the Banach space, provided $|t|<\epsilon$

@PieroD'Ancona To apply the Banach fixed point theorem? But, is the fact that the right-hand side is a contraction true under the general assumptions above? Taylor just assumes component-wise smoothness of $A$ and $g$ and nothing more.

This is only a long comment: The question is basically good but too broad to be answered properly on MO. Taylor's book has many gaps, and filling these would require writing a long exposition. For the particular matter of considering existence of a solution to the ODE obtained by mollifying the original PDE, one gets an equation of the form $y_\varepsilon'(t)=f_\varepsilon(t,y_\varepsilon(t))$ with $y$ having its values in the Banach space $H^k\hookrightarrow C\,(\mathbb R^n)$ and $f_\varepsilon$ continuous and Lipschitz w.r.t. the second argument. For the existence and regularity of $y_\varepsilon$ one can use e.g. the theory given in Chapter IV, pp. 61−90 in (my 1988 edition of) Serge Lang's book Differential Manifolds. Then it is another matter get the necessary estimates to show that the family of continuous functions $u_\varepsilon(t,x)=y_\varepsilon(t)(x)$ suitably converges as $\varepsilon\searrow 0$.

Thank you very much!
